# Magento 2 default menu call in phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, menu

I want to magento default menu in my other phtml file. how to call it?

I didn't found any code for menu please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want Top Menu in CMS Page then you can use below code in CMS Page.

```
{{block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml"}}
```

But as you mention you want in another Phtml then you can try to put belove code in Phtml.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Default Menu render by class `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`
In `default.xml` layout module-theme

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
      </arguments>
      <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
</block>
```

You can change template to new template you want. All content of menu render by class Topmenu. You can extend this class if you need customize menu